# Magento (1.7.0.2) DHL XML Service Issue with Production URL

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm having trouble with the Magento's default DHL shipping module. According to the debug log. The request sent out to the test Gateway URL @ https://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet seems to return the response as expected. However, when I switched the gateway to the production one @ https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet, the response returned as empty string (blank).

Here is an example of the request XML from the debug log file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes" xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd ">
   <GetQuote>
      <Request>
         <ServiceHeader>
            <SiteID>[hidden]</SiteID>
            <Password>[hidden]</Password>
         </ServiceHeader>
      </Request>
      <From>
         <CountryCode>BR</CountryCode>
         <Postalcode>04602000</Postalcode>
         <City>SÃ£o Paulo</City>
      </From>
      <BkgDetails>
         <PaymentCountryCode>BR</PaymentCountryCode>
         <Date>2014-03-13</Date>
         <ReadyTime>PT10H00M</ReadyTime>
         <DimensionUnit>CM</DimensionUnit>
         <WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit>
         <Pieces>
            <Piece>
               <PieceID>1</PieceID>
               <Weight>17.5</Weight>
            </Piece>
         </Pieces>
         <PaymentAccountNumber>[hidden]</PaymentAccountNumber>
         <IsDutiable>Y</IsDutiable>
      </BkgDetails>
      <To>
         <CountryCode>BR</CountryCode>
         <Postalcode>03318-000</Postalcode>
         <City>TatuapÃ©</City>
      </To>
      <Dutiable>
         <DeclaredCurrency>BRL</DeclaredCurrency>
         <DeclaredValue>14299.48</DeclaredValue>
      </Dutiable>
   </GetQuote>
</p:DCTRequest>
```

Did anyone experience the same issue before and how did you fix it? I tried to contact Magento via the forum, twitter, and facebook, but never heard back from them.

Thank you,

Patt

Comment: Are you sending via SOAP or REST?